# Android App crashes immediately after starting while starting using a SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, crash, android-permissions

I created an App to test how to implement an SQLite database in an Android App. But the App didn't even start and I don't know what causes the troubles.
Here is my code:

The logcat:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText buckysInput;
    TextView buckysText;
    MyDBHandbler dbHandbler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buckysInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.buckysInput);
        buckysText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buckysText);
        dbHandbler = new MyDBHandbler(this, null, null, 1);
        printDatabase();
    }

    public void addButtonClicked(View view){
        Products products = new Products(buckysInput.getText().toString());
        dbHandbler.addProduct(products);
        printDatabase();

    }
    public  void deleteButtonClicked(View view){
        String input = buckysInput.getText().toString();
        dbHandbler.deletProduct(input);
        printDatabase();
    }



    public void printDatabase() {
        String dbString = dbHandbler.databaseToString();
        buckysText.setText(dbString);
        buckysInput.setText("");
    }
}
```

My SQLiteOpenHelperClass:

```
public class MyDBHandbler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "products.db";
    public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS="products";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";

    public MyDBHandbler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" +
                COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "TEXT" +
                ");";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //Add a new row to the database
    public void addProduct(Products products){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, products.get_productname());
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
        db.close();

    }

    //Delet Product from the database
    public void deletProduct(String productName){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELET FROM" + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "WHERE" + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME  +"=\"" + productName + "\";");
    }

    //Print out the databse as a String
    public String databaseToString(){
        String dbString ="";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM" + TABLE_PRODUCTS +"WHERE 1";

        //Cursor point to a location in your results
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        while(!c.isAfterLast()){
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"))!= null){
                dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"));
                dbString += "\n";
            }
        }
        db.close();
        return dbString;
    }

}
```

Products class:

```
package com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple;

/**
* Created by phili on 29.07.2017.
*/

public class Products {

    private int _id;
    private String _productname;

    public  Products(){
    }

    public Products(String _productname){
        this._productname = _productname;
    }

    public void set_id(int _id){
        this._id = _id;
    }
    public void set_productname(String _productname){
        this._productname = _productname;
    }

    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public String get_productname() {
        return _productname;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
Logcat

:23838-23838/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
    23838-23852/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
    23838-23838/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
    23838-23838/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
    23838-23838/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
    23838-23838/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status

                                                      [ 07-29 20:26:08.842  3724: 3724 E/         ]
                                                      process stopped due to unexpected signal 13
    23838-23838/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
    23838-23838/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
    23838-23838/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
    23838-23838/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
    23838-23838/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
    23838-23838/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
    23838-23838/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
    23838-23838/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple-1/lib/arm
    23838-23838/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
    23838-23838/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl
    23838-23838/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
    23838-23838/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple E/SQLiteLog: (1) 
    23838-23838/com.example.phili.sqlitesmaple I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 23838 SIG: 9
```

I think it must be a problem with the SQLite Database because without it works fine.
 I hope you can help me. Greeting from Germany.

Comment: First thing to post should be crash log.

Comment: Use LogCat to find the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've added the logcat.

Comment: checking your code wait for a while

Answer (score 0):

One thing to definitely fix is the spaces in your onCreate SQL statement. With string concatenation, the SQL statement is invalid:

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
        COLUMN_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" +
        COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "TEXT" +
        ");";
```

would resolve to...

```
CREATE TABLE products(_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENTproductnameTEXT);
```

This is true in all the SQL statements too including the drop and select.

Answer (score 0):

donot use printDatabase(); because in first time your databases has no value and it will probally return null so donot use this method on **OnCreate**

first your insert query is wrong no spaces and commas

**your query**

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" +
                COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "TEXT" +
                ");";
```

result no spaces and also comma is missing

```
CREATE TABLE products(_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENTproductnameTEXT);
```

**modified query**

```
 String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"+", " +
                COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT" +
                ");";
```

result

```
CREATE TABLE products(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, productname TEXT);
```

and second in your databaseToString method your query is wrong use below

```
    // type e.g id , productname
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS +" WHERE type = 1";
```